# Specifying pool name for Oracle DRCP in Ruby/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oracle, connection-pooling

My team is transitioning from PHP to Rails, and our DBA has some concerns about how our Rails applications connect to the database.

Our PHP applications use DRCP to connect to a specific connection pool, specified with `ini_set('oci8.connection_class', 'POOLNAME')`.  This gives the DBA more control over how connections are managed across our applications.

For our Rails applications, the DBA would like us to use the same strategy, but as far as I can tell, in [ruby-oci8](http://ruby-oci8.rubyforge.org/en/) (version 2.1.5), you can only create a new connection pool:

```
pool = OCI8::ConnectionPool.new(1, 5, 2, 'usr', 'pwd', 'connection_string')
```

There doesn't seem to be a way to specify the name of--and connect to--an existing connection pool.

The JDBC adapter supports this feature, but to use that in Rails would require moving to JRuby, and we don't want to do that.

Before my team dives into the ruby-oci8 source code, is there a way to connect to an existing Oracle DRCP pool in Ruby by specifying the pool name?  If not, are there technical reasons why ruby-oci8 does not provide the ability to connect to an existing pool by name?